# Django Migrations stuck after executing in incorrect order

Tags: django, django-migrations

I made two changes to different models in my database.
The first

```
operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Settlement',
        ),
    ]
```

And the second:

```
operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='invoice',
            name='settlement_deducted',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='invoice',
            name='settlement_supporting',
        ),
]
```

The issue is that they ran in this order, and the second one failed. The field being removed in the second migration uses the "Settlement" model, but since that model was deleted in the first migration it throws this error:

```
ValueError: The field invoices.Invoice.settlement_deducted was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounting.settlement', but app 'accounting' doesn't provide model 'settlement'.
The field invoices.Invoice.settlement_supporting was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounting.settlement', but app 'accounting' doesn't provide model 'settlement'
```

Now when I try to do anything to fix it, it seems to just be stuck in that error state and continuously throws that same error.
I have tried reverting the first migration to the previous migration on that model, adding that model back in and running makemigrations and then migrate so that the Settlement model exists again, and deleting the second migration (though it was never run anyway). All of these options are still throwing the same error.

I am surprised that Django didn't catch this dependency issue for me, but it is unfortunately too late for that now. I also tried adding it as a dependency, but then it just threw the error saying that a migration has been migrated before one of its dependencies.

Comment: Did you try  recreate model and apply its migration before the last migration?

Comment: @kamilyrb yes I did, but it's almost like the error is thrown in some sort of migration state, as it keeps throwing the same error even though Im trying to do a migration on a completely different model (trying to re-create the original model). It also throws the error when I try to rewind the migration to the previous one for that application

Comment: Were these migrations made in separate branches in version control, that might explain how you ended up with this problem, although Django still should have detected conflicting migrations in that case.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I should have included that, thank you. These migrations were created individually and ran by the same person in the same branch, but were ran in reverse order (second, and then first). Once the branch was pushed up and pulled down by other people, there was no dependency made between the two migrations and they ran in the order shown in the question automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successfully able to solve the issue! These are the steps I took:

1. add the second migration as a dependency to the first one
2. go to the django_migrations table in the db and delete the first migration (which ran already)
3. run ONLY the second migration
4. fake the first migration (since it already ran)
5. (unnecessary step but necessary in my case) run migrate normally to finish migrating uninvolved migrations from other apps

Answer (score -1):

insite try this

```
py manage.py migrate <yourappname> zero
```

then go in the same app folder and in that migration folder delete all the file except pycache and init.py and then again try to run

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate
```

and please do replace py with python if you are using any other Os then windows what the migrate zero do is it delete all the migration of your app and after again doing the migration it will get everything back for you

and tell me if you still got any other error

Comment: I recognize that deleting my migrations and database would work, but this is a production environment so this is not an option. I also can't just delete and re-create the migrations because the second migration shown has not been run. If I deleted the migrations and then faked the migrations to allow it to realign with the existing database without losing data, I would have an error in the database because the two fields that were removed in the second migration never got removed since the migration didn't run. Therefore, those two columns would be a leak and still exist unknown to django.